# Smallest singular value interpretation as inverse spectral norm?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, svd, singular-values

The largest singular value of a finite dimensional matrix is its spectral norm (L2 operator norm). In other words, it is the maximum scaling that A does to any vector. Does the smallest singular value have any interesting properties? For instance, if the singular values are all lower bounded by 0, then could $\sigma_{min}$ it be interpreted as a kind of "inverse" spectral norm; i.e. the *minimum* the matrix must scale any vector?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: $\sigma_{min}^2$ is the least eigenvalue of $A^* A$, which is the minimum of 
$x^* A^* A x = \|A x\|^2$ for $x$ with $\|x\| = 1$.

Comment: Can you explain why this is the case and provide a source? Does this imply that if $A$ has n distinct eigenvalues, then the smallest one (by magnitude) is the minimum amount A must scale the vector?

Comment: 1) If $T$ is hermitian and $\lambda$ its least eigenvalue, $T - \lambda I$ is positive semidefinite, so $x^*(T-\lambda I) x \ge 0$.
2) No, it does not.  This is about singular values, not eigenvalues.

Comment: Interesting, I don't see why $x^*(T-\lambda I)x \geq 0$ shows that the $\lambda$ is the smallest scaling that can be done. How is the definition of PSD related to scaling? What if T is non-square, let alone Hermitian?

Comment: I'm using $T = A^* A$.  $x^* (A^* A - \lambda I) x = \|A x\|^2 - \lambda \|x\|^2$, so if this $\ge 0$, it says $\|Ax\| \ge \sqrt{\lambda} \|x\|$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So the key is $x^TA^TAx = \|Ax\|^2$, and then we have an expression for the norm and can conclude immediately based on the fact that $A^TA-\lambda I$ is PSD. But you haven't shown that $\lambda$ is the smallest such scaling possible. For instance, your argument also holds if we plug in $\lambda_{max}$, but we know that clearly the minimum scaling is not the largest singular value.

Comment: $A^T A - \lambda_{min}I$ is PSD, but not $A^T A - \lambda_{max} I$: instead $\lambda_{max} I - A^T A$ is PSD, so $\lambda_{max} \|x\|^2 \ge \|A x\|^2$.

Comment: Okay, we still have not shown that $\lambda_{min}$ is the smallest scaling. We have only shown that $A^TA-\lambda_{min}I$ is PSD, which is good but not enough. I think you have an intuitive argument, but don't think it is rigorous. EDIT: Actually, this makes complete sense, thank you. You are correct.

Comment: The reasoning is that we have directly shown that regardless of if there is some $\lambda_{\epsilon} < \lambda_{min} $, we have from our equation that $\|Ax\| \geq \sqrt{\lambda_{min}}\|x\|$, so it must scale by at least this much

Comment: One final question, is this a general result? I believe your equation holds without any assumptions, i.e $\lambda_{min}$ can be negative and it handles the case where A has linearly dependent columns. If so, why have I not seen a proof of this useful lemma you have given anywhere?